# Why the for loop doesn't stop at i == 0 in strangeForLoop?

Tags: c

I tried the following code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Also tried it on Mac.

Couldn't find out why the for loop in strangeForLoop will not stop when i is equal to 0?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void strangeForLoop();
void normalForLoop();

const uint32_t COUNTDOWN = 3;
int BREAK = -2;

int main()
{
    strangeForLoop();
    printf("\n===========\n");
    normalForLoop();
    return 0;
}

void strangeForLoop() {
    for(uint32_t i = COUNTDOWN; i>=0; i--) {
        printf("strange i : %d\n", i);
        
        if (i == 0) 
            printf("--> i: %d\n", i);
        if (i == BREAK) break;
    }
}

void normalForLoop() {
    for(int i = COUNTDOWN; i>=0; i--) {
        printf("normal i : %d\n", i);
        
        if (i == 0) 
            printf("==> i: %d\n", i);
        if (i == BREAK) break;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because `i` is an `unsigned` and can never be < 0

Comment: When `i == 0` and you do `i--` at the end of the loop, the value of `i` will "wrap" and become really big.

Comment: As you run the code, you will notice that "--> i: 0" is printed.

Comment: Also note that the `printf` format `%d` is for plain `int`, which is *signed*, while `i` is *unsigned*. Mismatching format specifier and argument value type leads to *undefined behavior*. If you use `%u` instead, you will see what really happens with `i`.

Comment: Try %u, and still prints out "0"

Comment: The point is that (i == 0) is "true". So why doesn't the for loop stop?

Comment: @David Ranieri However, when i reaches 0, the for loop should be stopped. Isn't that this should be the case?

Comment: Because the `for` loop condition `i>=0;` is `true`. That is the condition for the loop to continue. It is never `false` as explained.

Comment: OTOH `if (i == BREAK) break;` will work when `BREAK = -2` because the integer conversion rules apply to `-2`.

Comment: The loop does not stop when `i` reaches zero.  The loop stop when `i` is less than zero.  Which is never true.

Comment: Both David and Weather are right. Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is an [unsigned integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signedness). Such a `uint` can represent only positive values and zero;

`[0, 1, 2, 3, ... 2^number_of_bits - 1]`

When an operation would decrease a uint below zero, or above its maximum, an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs.

In the case of this code, it wraps around to the maximum value for the integer, so the condition `i >= 0` will always remain true, and the loop will never stop.

Comment: By standard explicit definition unsigned integers do not overflow. That is because they do not represent natural numbers, but they represent equivalence classes. Standard quotes on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54190216/2805305) and more discussion in the comments there.

Comment: @bolov: Yes, the definition in the ISO C standard for the word "overflow" is different from the common definition. However, in my opinion, it is still correct to use the word "overflow" in this context. That just means that the common definition is being used instead of the definition used in the ISO C standard.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel yes, that is exactly what I did in my linked answer. However I do feel it is important to at least note the standard definition.