# conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'int' requires a narrowing conversion

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, type-conversion, integer, unsigned

My code includes the following, and I get the error message above based on the last line below.

```
struct List {
    int word_i;
    int mod_i;
    char mod_type;
    char mod_char;
};

struct Morph {
    Options mode;
    deque<List> search_list;
    vector<string> dictionary;
    vector<bool> discovered;
    string output;
    int sel_word_i = 0;
    bool end_found = 0;
};

// later on in a function:
morph->search_list.push_back({ morph->dictionary.size() - 1, 0, 0, 0 });
```

Comment: `morph->dictionary.size()` returns a `size_t` which is unsigned. In order to use it that way you'll need a cast to `int`.

Comment: When `size()` returns 0, what's `0 - 1`?

Comment: Are you wondering why the compiler reports that waring? Are you concerned with how to remove the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the last line with:

```
morph->search_list.emplace_back( morph->dictionary.size() - 1, 0, 0, 0 );
```

Thus the object is created not through brace initialization which does not allow narrowing conversion.

The narrowing conversion is from the return value of the call to `size` which returns `std::size_t` which is unsigned.

For why `size() - 1` is not converted to a signed value see: [C++ Implicit Conversion (Signed + Unsigned)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832815/c-implicit-conversion-signed-unsigned)

Comment: So that solved that error, but now I get the following:
term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument

Comment: @FranciscoSkrobola - Read carefully.   You need to change the member function being called from `push_back()` to `emplace_back()`.  The two are not interchangeable when you're trying to construct and add and object.

Comment: I did change it but doing so caused the evaluation error

Answer (score 0):

When and after you applied what Amir suggested, you may get an error saying something like, "this function does not take (3) arguments." To fix that you'll have to declare a constructor in the class, which you used for your vector, that takes that particular number of arguments. From what I understood when you replace `push_back();` with `emplace_back();`the compiler thinks that you're trying to pass some variables to the constructor, which are the supposed arguments.

Comment: Vector element type does not *need* to have a constructor in C++20 though. `emplace_back` uses placement-new in the form of `new(p) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` under the hood (except in exotic custom allocator cases), i.e. uses `()` brackets form (*direct initialization*) which didn't trigger aggregate initialization for aggregate types without suitable constructor before C++20, but now does due to [p0960](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html). So, aggregates even without appropriate parametrized constructors can now be initialized within `emplace_back`.